# transferring a keypair to an ubuntu instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, ubuntu-16.04

I have added a new user to my instance. I would like to transfer the pem file to that account so I can complete the instructions of adding a user (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/new-user-accounts-linux-instance/). I am in the section that details me creating a key pair and now I would like to transfer it from my computer to the new user account in my instance. Every time I do it, I get a timeout failure:

> (ssh: connect to host ip-XXX-xxx-xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22:
>   Operation timed out lost connection).

I am using below command to connect to the instance:

> scp -i ~/.ssh/my.pem ~/Downloads/new.pem
>   ubuntu@ip-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/directory/.

I already added port 22 with my ip as a rule and also `chmod 400 new.pem` and rebooted. Please help!

Comment: Use the -v flag for a more verbose output and share the logs so that the issue can be debugged. In your case, the command would look like `scp -vi ~/.ssh/my.pem ~/Downloads/new.pem ubuntu@ip-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/directory/.`

Comment: I needed to follow the directions further down. my apologies. The instructions seem to be a bit unclear.

Comment: Are you able to login as ec2-user to that instance? Timeout is a different problem, usually a network/firewall issue, not security. Also post output of `ssh -vvv ubuntu@ip-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com` and `ssh -vvv ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: @dsmith: Just replace the `-i` in the `scp` command you wrote in the question with `-vi` and share the output.